# Who can attend UDS?

Tags: uds

I Live near Hungary (Slovakia), so it isn't a big trip to came to Budapest UDS. But I don't know who can attend this event. Everyone? Or just the community members? Is it needs to register somewhere? And if I haven't rent a room yet, can I rent it the Grand Hotel (how much it is?), or it is only for members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UDS is an open event and everyone is welcome.

The [travel page](http://uds.ubuntu.com/travel/) has a form where you can contact the hotel and get a discounted rate. We do ask that you [register](https://forms.canonical.com/udsreg/) though so we can get an accurate headcount for food and so on.

Hope to see you there!

Answer (score 2):

That's a really good question.  I'm pretty sure anyone can come, as long as you register (at zero charge.)  You can stay at the hotel if there is a room free, or [there are some other option](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UDS-O/OtherAccommodation).